# How to write an Hermitian operator as one single outer product?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators

Suppose $\hat A$ is an Hermitian operator in a (finite dimensional) Hilbert space. A has discrete eigenkets $|\alpha_i\rangle $ with eigenvalues $\alpha_i$. Then $\hat A$ can be written as $\sum_i\,\alpha_i|\alpha_i\rangle\langle\alpha_i|$. I have also understood that any operator can be written as one single outer product in the form $|a\rangle\langle b|$. But I am not able to do this for above Hermitian operator. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 1):

Start with
$$
\hat A=\sum_{ij}\alpha_{ij}\vert i\rangle\langle j\vert
$$
with $\alpha_{ji}=\alpha_{ij}^*$.
You should be able to deduce the coefficients $\alpha_{ij}$ using matrix elements of $\hat A$.

As an example, compare
\begin{align}
\sigma_x=\vert +\rangle\langle - \vert  + \vert -\rangle\langle +\vert
\end{align}
with its matrix representation.

Note that if your operator is Hermitian and non-diagonal, it cannot be written as a *single* term of the type $\hat A=\vert a\rangle\langle b\vert$ since then $\hat A^\dagger = \vert b\rangle\langle a\vert \ne \hat A$

Answer (score 1):

Your claim

> "I have also understood that any operator can be written as one
> single outer product in the form $|a⟩⟨b|$"

is not possible. You cannot write any operator generally as a single outer product in the form
$$
\hat O \neq |a\rangle \langle b|
$$
That is only possible in some special cases. The general way to write an operator in a discrete basis is
$$
\hat O= \sum_{ij} c_{ij}|i\rangle \langle j|
$$
which is a sum of outer products.